# Batch file. 7Zip photo folder and name output as job number

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, batch-processing, 7zip

1st off I am not very familiar with advanced programming. I have been following examples and trial and erroring things sometimes with not the right result.

I was up half the night trying to get this to work and was so close but not quite there.
Basically I have a folder structure like this.
JOB NUMBER/Photos
In the photo folder there are 2 sub folders Hi-Res & Low-Res

I need a bat file in the Photos folder that will zip only the JPG in folder Low-Res then name the output zip file as JOB NUMBER - Photos.zip and save it to the photo folder.

On top of this once I had it working I need the zip files to be limited on their size. They must be not larger than 6mb so if they need splitting a simple 01 02 .... Can be prefixed to the zip name.
I briefly saw that you could split the output based on size but didn't get that far!

Any help would be a life saver!!

UPDATE

My code so far.

```
for %%A in ("%%~dp0\..") do 7z a -tzip "%%~fA-Photos.zip" "Low-Res"
```

UPDATE
@JonathonReinhart
This gets the Low-res contents zipped & saved back into the Low-res folder which will be fine I just cant get the name on the zip file right. At the moment it saves as Photos-Photos.zip

`for %%A in ("Low-res\Photos") do 7z a -tzip "%%~fA-Photos.zip" "Low-Res"`

Comment: Show what you've tried.

Comment: I will upload my code once I'm logged on I'm not on my PC yet using my phone so bear with me.

Comment: Updated post showing what i have cobbled together

Comment: Thanks Jonathon Reinhart. The edit you made creates a zip file called Photos-Photos.zip in the main JOB-Number folder. I need the filename to be JOB NUMBER - Photos.zip & stored in the Photos folder if possible. This was the problem i was having last night

Comment: i have worked out how to get it to save to the Low-Res folder which will be fine but i just cant get the file name to be that of the JOB NUMBER main folder.   for %%A in ("Low-res\-Photos") do 7z a -tzip "%%~fA-Photos.zip" "Low-Res"

Comment: This is driving me mad it must be something simple. it has to be something to do with the %%~fA. But i cant work it out. Help!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test this in the photos folder.

```
@echo off
for %%z in ("%cd%") do (
   for %%a in ("%%~dpz%\.") do (
      7z a -tzip "%%~nxa-%%~nxz.zip" "Low-Res\*" 
   )
)
pause
```

Comment: Bingo, Works perfectly thank you! Much appreciated. Where can I learn all the tricks for CMD & BAT programming? is there any tutorial websites? I think im a bit out of depth here!!

Comment: Here is a FAQ list http://www.netikka.net/tsneti/info/tscmd.php and get the `tscmd.zip` file mentioned near the top for more sample scripts.  Reading batch forums and asking questions there is a good way of picking up tips, and changing then debugging scripts is a hands on way of learning.